# How to align right edges of a control and ToolTip Message in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, alignment, tooltip

I want to display a `ToolTip` message below a `TextBox`, but also want them to be right aligned.

I was able to position the ToolTip message at the right edge of the textbox, so I tried to move the message left by message length.

So I tried to get the string length by using *TextRenderer.MeasureText()*, but the position is a little bit off as shown below.

[image: current result]

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ToolTip myToolTip = new ToolTip();

   string test = "This is a test string.";
   int textWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText(test, SystemFonts.DefaultFont, textBox1.Size, TextFormatFlags.LeftAndRightPadding).Width;
   int toolTipTextPosition_X = textBox1.Size.Width - textWidth;

   myToolTip.Show(test, textBox1, toolTipTextPosition_X, textBox1.Size.Height);
}
```

I tried with different flags in the *MeasureText()* function but it didn't help, and since ToolTip message has a padding, I went for *TextFormatFlags.LeftAndRightPadding*.

To be clear, this is what I would like to achieve:

[image: desired output]

Comment: Try to replace SystemFonts.DefaultFont by myToolTip.Font.

Comment: @Graffito: There is no such thing. One can decide which Font to use when owner-drawing the ToolTip.

Comment: Sorry, Font is only available in the ToolTip.Draw event (with OwnerDraw = true).

Comment: Indeed, that is what I just wrote. And: In this event you can get the correct width needed for left-aligned placement..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set [`OwnerDraw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip.ownerdraw?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property of the `ToolTip` to true. Then you can control appearance and location of the tooltip in `Draw` event. In the following example, I've found the tooltip handle and moved it to the desired location using [`MoveWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-movewindow?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) Windows API function :

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll")]
static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr h, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool redraw);
private void toolTip1_Draw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    e.DrawBorder();
    e.DrawText();
    var t = (ToolTip)sender;
    var h = t.GetType().GetProperty("Handle",
      System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    var handle = (IntPtr)h.GetValue(t);
    var c = e.AssociatedControl;
    var location = c.Parent.PointToScreen(new Point(c.Right - e.Bounds.Width, c.Bottom));
    MoveWindow(handle, location.X, location.Y, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height, false);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The ToolTip font is bigger than SystemFonts.DefaultFont so the measurement is incorrect. I don't know what is the exact variable for the ToolTip font, but many of the other SystemFonts are configured to Segoe UI/size 9, which the Tooltip font in my PC. In addition, you have to add 6px for the padding.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolTip myToolTip = new ToolTip();

    string test = "This is a test string.";
    int textWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText(test, SystemFonts.CaptionFont, textBox1.Size, TextFormatFlags.LeftAndRightPadding).Width;
    textWidth += 6;
    int toolTipTextPosition_X = textBox1.Size.Width - textWidth;

    myToolTip.Show(test, textBox1, toolTipTextPosition_X, textBox1.Size.Height);
}
```

For perfect control you could draw the tooltip yourself with Tooltip.OwnerDraw and the event Tooltip.Draw, choosing font, padding and appearance.