# Winform ToolTip location setting

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tooltip

I'm wondering if it is possible somehow locate popup of ToolTip outside of application form in the fixed point over the empty desktop with MouseHover event, of course  if event is useful for ToolTip, not sure. Or any other way if it is possible

I'm not asking for how to display another form as an option for this goal.

Comment: Do you want to create a global click event handler? Because mouse clicks won't work outside of your program unless you build/use one.

Comment: It's unclear how you are trying to show ToolTip. It's better to add some code to show how you are showing it, then other users can try to solve positioning issue.

Comment: @EpicKip Hello, I've edited mistake above, I want popup ToolTip with   MouseHover  event over the textbox or form no matter, but  beside the application form for example with size 800x300 and in fixed location over  the empty desktop independently of the mouse arrow location.

Comment: @Reza Aghaei Hello, I got ToolTip settings in VS  properties, as popup  delay values etc. I don't have any code

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use either of these options:

1. Handle showing and hiding the `ToolTip` yourself. You can use `MouseHover` show the `ToolTip` in desired location and using `MouseLeave` hide it.
2. Using [`MoveWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-movewindow?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) Windows API method, force the tooltip to show in a specific location instead of default location.

**Option 1**

You can handle `MouseHover` and `MouseLeave` event of your control(s) and show `ToolTip` in specific location of desktop window this way:

```
private void control_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var control = (Control)sender;
    var text = toolTip1.GetToolTip(control);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        toolTip1.Show(text, control, control.PointToClient(new Point(100, 100)));
}
private void control_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var control = (Control)sender;
    toolTip1.Hide(control);
}
```

**Option 2**

As another option which I previously offered for [align right edges of a control and ToolTip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41314678/3110834), you can set [`OwnerDraw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip.ownerdraw?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property of `ToolTip` to `true` and handle `Draw` event of the control and use `MoveWindow` Windows API method to move `ToolTip` to desired location:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll")]
static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr h, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool redraw);
private void toolTip1_Draw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e) {
    e.DrawBackground();
    e.DrawBorder();
    e.DrawText();
    var t = (ToolTip)sender;
    var h = t.GetType().GetProperty("Handle",
      System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    var handle = (IntPtr)h.GetValue(t);
    var location = new Point(100,100);
    MoveWindow(handle, location.X, location.Y, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like ultimately what you want is a box to display some information whenever you hover over some particular items on your GUI. You also say that you want the information to display at a fixed point.

As opposed to achieving this with the tool-tip, I would do the following:

1. Create some fixed label or text-box to display information and put it somewhere on your Windows form.
2. Create a subscriber to the mouse hover event.
3. Based on the `sender` (which control you're hovering) from the mouse hover event, choose what information to display in the fixed location.

I've seen people doing this in some other programs... Take, [RealTerm](https://sourceforge.net/projects/realterm/) for example. Try it out if you want and see how it feels before you try this solution.

On the other hand, if you must do this with a tool-tip. You can choose the position using overloads of [ToolTip.Show](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.show.aspx).