# Tooltip Text going off screen (WinForms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tooltip

I've drawn on a Tool Tip control - The code is below.

```
private void toolTip1_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
        {
            ToolTip tt = (sender as ToolTip);
            string toolTipText = tt.GetToolTip(e.AssociatedControl);
            e.ToolTipSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(toolTipText, new Font("Arial", 16.0f));
        }
```

```
private void toolTip1_Draw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e) => DrawToolTip(sender, e);

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll")]
        static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr h, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool redraw);
        private void DrawToolTip(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e)
        {
            ToolTip tt = (sender as ToolTip);
            string toolTipText = tt.GetToolTip(e.AssociatedControl);
            Font f = new Font("Arial", 16.0f);
            e.DrawBackground();
            e.DrawBorder();
            toolTipText = e.ToolTipText;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(e.ToolTipText, f, Brushes.Black, new PointF(2, 2));
        }
```

And then to set the ToolTip text:

```
toolTip1.SetToolTip(btnLogin, "Some text.....");
```

Additionally, [here is an image of what is happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZh4N.png)

It looks alright, but it has come to my attention that if the text is a certain length, the tooltip will go off-screen. Is there anyway to prevent that? I would rather not have to add Environment.NewLine(); or \n etc, since I would need to do that for MANY strings.

Comment: There should be a DrawString overload that takes a Rectangle, no?

Comment: [How to increase ToolTip Rectangle size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53745899/7444103)

Comment: My issue is that the text is going off-screen, not that the rectangle is too small.

Comment: The DrawString overload will __limit__ the Text to the Rectangle's Width, so it should solve your issue..! - Btw: TextRenderer.MeasureText can also take a Size so you can make it __calculate the Height__ needed for a given Width...!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to combine the two solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53745899/7444103) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42536607/14171304) to mainly resize the `ToolTip` window with the screen width, and move it to `Point(2, 2)`, screen coordinates.

If that is what you need, you need to modify the source codes a bit to set the right `e.ToolTipSize` in the `Popup` event, and as the gentlemen commented above, draw the string in a rectangle, the `e.Bounds` property in the `Draw` event.

```cs
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter
    | TextFormatFlags.Left
    | TextFormatFlags.LeftAndRightPadding
    | TextFormatFlags.NoClipping
    | TextFormatFlags.WordBreak;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void toolTip1_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
    {
        var tt = sender as ToolTip;
        var toolTipText = tt.GetToolTip(e.AssociatedControl);
        var screen = Screen.FromControl(e.AssociatedControl).WorkingArea;

        using (var g = e.AssociatedControl.CreateGraphics())
        using (var font = new Font("Arial", 16))
        {
            var sz = TextRenderer.MeasureText(
                g, toolTipText, font, screen.Size, flags);

            e.ToolTipSize = new Size(screen.Width - 2, sz.Height + 10);
        }
    }

    private void toolTip1_Draw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e)
    {
        var t = sender as ToolTip;
        var h = (IntPtr)t.GetType().GetProperty("Handle",
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(t);

        MoveWindow(h, 2, 2, e.Bounds.Width - 2, e.Bounds.Height, false);

        e.DrawBackground();
        e.DrawBorder();

        using (var font = new Font("Arial", 16))
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.ToolTipText, font, 
                e.Bounds, Color.Black, flags);
    }

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr h, int x, int y, 
        int width, int height, bool redraw);

}
```

[image: SOQ65526197]

Comment: Wow, the screen width is a bit large for a friendly tooltip, no? Best measure the height needed for a mor resonabl width, no?

Comment: @Taw Hello smart. Right, I'd do what you are saying. But this is what I understand from the question. no? :) Happy 2021.

Comment: Same to you. Yup, it is up the poster to decide on the best width ; I don't think he understood that the measurer can __limit either the height or the width__ and calulate the other dimension..

Comment: `var screen = Screen.FromControl(e.AssociatedControl);` and `using (var g = e.AssociatedControl.CreateGraphics())`. Use TextRenderer to both measure and draw the Text (I've also updated the answer you linked). The .Net's ToolTip uses TextRenderer to draw the text.