# Determining ToolTip size before ToolTip.Show

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tooltip

I'm using a custom `ToolTip` in a derived Control, using `ToolTip.Show(String, IWin32Window, Int32, Int32)` method, when I call this method I already know the mouse position.

It works well except that I cannot position the `ToolTip` well. I need to show `ToolTip` right above the mouse cursor. Let's say the mouse is at x,y then I need the tooltip's *lower left* corner to be at x, y-2. But `ToolTip.Show` wants the *upper left* coordinates of upcoming `ToolTip`.

Therefore I would have to calculate the height of the upcoming `ToolTip`.
How to do this?

Comment: You have asked 10 questions without accepting an answer. Please take a [tour] and then review your previous questions and answers and upvote useful answers and from useful answers accept and upvote the best one.

Comment: You should set `OwnerDraw` property your `ToolTip`  to true. Then you can find its size using `e.Bounds`. Then to show the `ToolTip` in desired location, use `MoveWindow` Windows API function. Take a look at this post: [How to align right edges of a control and ToolTip Message in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41314678/how-to-align-right-edges-of-a-control-and-tooltip-message-in-c-sharp).

Comment: In the linked post just change the location to `var location = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y- e.Bounds.Height);`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out accepting answers and linking the other post. However, it seems that the real answer to my original question is 'it simply cannot be done this way'. And if one wishes to avoid P/Invoke (for portability to mono) then .net API failed to do this simple thing. Sad...

Comment: You're welcome. You can make your code independent from height calculation by deciding to align top-left of ToolTip to bottom-right of mouse location.